# "key violation" when trying to import data into MS Access

Tags: ms-access, unique-constraint, import

I am trying to import data into an MS Access table from a flat ASCII file.  I've done this many times before but now I am getting a "key violation."  There is only one key in the table and it's an autonumber, so this is not just a simple matter of duplicating previous keys.  I have looked over other potential problems like integrity violations but have found nothing.  So: Does MS Access keep any more detailed records about which field(s) have the problem exactly?  And if so, how to I call this information up?  Thanks.

Addendum:  I kept hitting the import button and trying to think of what else there might be to examine and then, lo and behold, it worked.  I didn't change anything.  It just worked all of a sudden.  Anyone ever hear of this happening?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps some of the data was successfully imported, and on your subsequent attempts it tries to reimport the whole file, and collides with the existing data?  More generally, are there any records in the target table with which it could be colliding?

If that's not the case, try cutting the file in half.  Can you import the first half?  If so, the problem is in the second half.  Recurse to isolate the problem record(s).